# units::set_units() won't recognise units from an variable

Tags: r, units-of-measurement

How can I read units into the `units` package from a variable? I get the error `...not recognised by udunits`. An MWE below:

```
library(units)
measurements <- runif(10)
unitsofmeasurement <- "mm"
set_units(measurements, unitsofmeasurement)
```

returns the error

```
Error: In ‘unitsofmeasurement’, ‘unitsofmeasurement’ is not recognized by udunits.
```

but the following works:

```
set_units(measurements, "mm")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is some information about this on the help page for `as_units`.  You can get the behavior you want by setting the mode to "standard".

```
units_options(set_units_mode = "standard")
set_units(measurements, unitsofmeasurement)

Units: mm
 [1] 0.33276818 0.16444913 0.07442400 0.15536703 0.13068749 0.08494946 0.86531095
 [8] 0.40301657 0.78669608 0.14237601
```

Comment: I missed this the first time I read the help page. Fixed by adding `mode = "standard"` to the `set_units()` function.